# A tool for rearranging tiles in a tileset, visually

Tags: image-editor, utility, pixel-graphics

While I can definitely use ImageMagick's `-crop` and `-tile` commands for doing this, a tool with a interactive UI (drag and drop function) is more preferable when working with tilesets and especially terrains.
Basicly any tool which splits the image into a regular grid of, say, 16x16 pixel tiles and allows dragging them to new locations of the same grid, will suffice.